# How to rotate matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, data-structures

Consider the matrix 'm1' :

```
m1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
```

The question is, how to rotate the 'm1' data 45 degrees and extract the matrix 'm2' from it (shown in the fig. below) ?:
[image]

Comment: One can observe that `m2` has dimensions $50\times50$. Therefore, `m2=m1[[26;;75,26;;75]]`. I have to add that you do not provide all the details, is the rotation clock wise in both cases?

Comment: In the first step, the 'm1' matrix data should be rotated e.g. 45 degrees to the right and then the 'm2' matrix should be extracted.

Comment: How would `m2` look like for  the numeric array `m1 = Partition[Range[16],4]`?

Comment: @kglr. Such a matrix has too small dimension.

Comment: I guess it's not possible :(

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps something like

```
ClearAll[dM, dMValues, labeledMatrixPlot, rotatedMatrixPlot]

dM[mat_] := (DiamondMatrix[All, Dimensions @ mat] /. 0 -> "") mat /. Times["", _] -> ""

dMValues[mat_] := Values @ KeySort @
   GroupBy[SparseArray[DiamondMatrix[All, Dimensions @ mat]][
     "NonzeroPositions"], -Total @ # &, Extract[mat, Reverse @ #] &]

labeledMatrixPlot = MatrixPlot[#, ##2, 
    ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, Mesh -> All, 
    ColorRules -> "" -> White, 
    FrameTicks -> {{#, #}, {#, #}} & @ Range[Length @ #], 
    Epilog -> MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, Small], Reverse @ #2 - .5] &, #, {2}]] &;

rotatedMatrixPlot[mp_] := Show[MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, 
      RotationTransform[Pi/4, Mean /@ PlotRange[mp]]] &, mp, {1}] /. 
   Text[a_, pos_] :> 
    Text[a, RotationTransform[Pi/4, {n/2, n/2}] @ pos], Frame -> False]
```

**Examples:**

```
n = 7;

SeedRandom[1]

m1 = Round[RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, n}], .01];

Multicolumn[{labeledMatrixPlot[m1],
   labeledMatrixPlot[dM @ m1], 
   rotatedMatrixPlot[labeledMatrixPlot[dM @ m1]], 
   dMValues @ m1 // Grid // Style[#, 24] &}, 
 2, Appearance -> "Horizontal", Alignment -> Center]
```

[image]

Use `n = 8` above to get

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's close now. The last result is not a matrix, i.e. has a number of columns / rows 5 and 6.  But that's easy to reduce to a 5x5 matrix.

Comment: How to obtain the data from the last figure (only those in colored boxes) as a list?

Comment: @ralph, please see the update.